# Applying topological definition of continuity

Tags: general-topology

I am a physics student and have just recently started studying about topology. I am trying to apply the topological definition of continuity in this function.
$$f:(0,2)\rightarrow(0,1]\cup(2,3)$$ 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x, & \text{ if } x \in (0,1]\\
x+1, &\text{ if } x \in (1,2)
\end{cases}$$

I think that the co-domain of this function is not a topological space because the co-domain itself is not an open set and so it doesn't fit in the definition of a topology. So, is it so that we can't apply topological definition in this case or am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: Is $(0,1]$ an open set in the codomain? If so, then its inverse under $f$ must be an open set in $(0,2)$ in order for $f$ to be continuous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set $\left(0, 1\right] = \left(0, \frac32\right) \cap \Big((0,1] \cup (2,3)\Big)$ is an open set in the codomain $(0,1] \cup (2,3)$. We have

$$f^{-1}\Big(\left(0, 1\right]\Big) = \left(0, 1\right]$$

which is not an open set in $(0,2)$. Therefore $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but it might be because even though this answer is a valid proof of the discontinuity of the function is doesn't answer the questions asked by the OP.

Comment: I didn't downvote. I am still trying to understand the answers.

Comment: Why is this open $\left(0, 1\right] = \left(0, \frac32\right) \cap \Big((0,1] \cup (2,3)\Big)$?  I recall reading somewhere that we say that a set is open to the set it's contained in, not the larger metric space.  If that's true then why is this set open in the codomain

Comment: @johnfowles Let $X$ be a topological space and $Y \subseteq X$. A set $A \subseteq Y$ is said to be open in $Y$ if there exists $U \subseteq X$ open in $X$ such that $A = U \cap Y$. In this case I took $X = \mathbb{R}$, $Y = (0,1] \cup (2,3)$, $A = (0,1]$ and $U = \left(0, \frac32\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

Every subset of a topological space inherits a default topology from its containing space, called, unsurprisingly, the "subspace topology". (You can look up this term on, say, Wikipedia, or in any topology text to read more details about it.) This is certainly the topology that is intended for $(0.1] \cup (2,3)$ (considered as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with its usual topology), and it does make it into a valid topological space.

But you'll have to be careful, as the definition of subspace topology can lead to some surprises for a first-time student. For instance, $(0,1]$ is an **open subset** of $(0.1] \cup (2,3)$, even though it is not an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. (@mechanodroid uses this fact in their proof that the function is not continuous.)